# Contents of embedded.mobileprovision always remains constant?

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa, mobileprovision

Does the contents of embedded.mobileprovision change when I submit the ipa to the app store or after app becomes live? I don't think it should change but I need to be sure about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of the embeded provisioning profile doesn't change unless and untill you make the changes in it.

For instance, if you add/remove new devices from profile then provisioning profile is changed. So you need to downliad it and create a .ipa file from updated provisioning profile.

In short, if make changes in provisioning profile then the content of the provisioning profile is changed.